# Java handle image with radioButton

Tags: java, image, swing, radio-button

I am trying to Add an image to a jLabel.  Whenever the user clicks radiobutton "Single", or "Double" the jLabel should contain an image of a single or double room.

If rdbDouble(radio button) is clicked the program should do:

```
private void rdbDoubleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Image imageSingle;
        try {
            imageSingle = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Tegnikon\\2014\\Java\\Assignments\\Semester 2\\HotelBookingSrvice\\ProjectResources\\Double hotel Room.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        if(rdbDouble.isSelected())
        {
         rdbDouble.setIcon(imageSingle);
        }
    }
```

Code throws an error at the "rdbDouble.setIcon(imageSingle);" statement. Erros says, the required and found image is not in the same format.

Please tell me what can I do to get this right

Comment: i believe this has to do with the fact that your using a jpg format. try using a .png format or using a different class to handle the image such as a `bitmap`. related external link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: You are trying to add  image to the RadioButton and not JLabel as it looks from your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it takes an Icon and not Image. See the [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) setIcon() method for details. In you case you should try

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(imageSingle);
rdbDouble.setIcon(icon);
```

One more thing I can see in your code is that ypu are adding image to a RadioButton and not JLabel.